# Use Azure DNS if local DNS not available

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM which is a DNS Server.
If this server goes down, is it possible for the other VM's in the same Vnet to then switch over to Azure DNS?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you are affraid the DNS might become unavailable, rather configure it for high availability instead:

- Create an [availability set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability) in Azure
- Create multiple instances of your DNS server inside the availability set and set them to replicate each other

However, if you are running Windows, then this seems to be something you can configure inside your VMs. Just, in my ears it sounds very hackish to rely on in case of an outage, see answer [link](https://serverfault.com/a/84293/316273) for more info. Shortly:

> The DNS Client service queries the DNS servers in the following order:
>
> 1. The DNS Client service sends the name query to the first DNS server
>      on the preferred adapter’s list of DNS servers and waits one second
>      for a response.
> 2. If the DNS Client service does not receive a response from the first
>      DNS server within one second, it sends the name query to the first
>      DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration and
>      waits two seconds for a response.
> 3. If the DNS Client service does not receive a response from any DNS
>      server within two seconds, the DNS Client service sends the query to
>      all DNS servers on all adapters that are still under consideration
>      and waits another two seconds for a response.
> 4. If the DNS Client service still does not receive a response from any
>      DNS server, it sends the name query to all DNS servers on all
>      adapters that are still under consideration and waits four seconds
>      for a response.
> 5. If it the DNS Client service does not receive a response from any
>      DNS server, the DNS client sends the query to all DNS servers on all
>      adapters that are still under consideration and waits eight seconds
>      for a response.

Comment: Part of my problem is that my secondary DNS is in another azure region, the two regions in question cannot be Peered as azure does not currently offer it for these regions, but the VM's in the first vNET wont be able to resolve dns to connect to the secondary DNS if the primary DNS goes down... does this make sense?

Comment: Global VNet peering is something that is in public preview at the moment https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/global-vnet-peering-preview/ and you can sign up for if you want to try it. Just keep in mind it's a preview. If you want you can also set up a vpn tunnel and create a vnet-to-vnet tunnel. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal for more info on how to do that

Comment: Yeh I came in the office this morning with the objective of setting up the peering, just to find its not yet being previewed in the regions I am working on, DOH! and VPN Tunnel was my next solution but I have been told I cannot do this by my management as it incurs extra cost.

Comment: I understand =\ if it's of any help you can use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ to give them a rough estimate of costs and set up NSG's to minimize the traffic, tho traffic is most likely not what will cost the most